# Grails messages.properties typeMismatch error messages

Tags: validation, grails, error-handling, gsp

I have a User domain class that has an enum field in it called Gender. It has values for male and female in it. When I represent it on the GSP page it appears as a drop down. To test the security of the web app, I used firebug to alter the value of male which was 0 to abc to see if the validation catches it. I does but the message it showed wasn't human readable. I used  the following in my messages.properties.

```
typeMismatch.User.gender=The value for {0} is {1} and it is not a valid value
```

But the problem is, when my GSP renders the Errors, It doesn't replace {1} with the rejected value of the drop down list. I tried {2} and {3} and etc, it only prints them as String and don't replace them. Is there a way to get the rejectedValue in the message ?

Updated: I have toString method in my enum Gender too. Here is some code from controller and gsp page.

Controller:

```
if (bioInstance.hasErrors() || currentUser.hasErrors()) {                               
    render(view: 'editProfile', model: [user: currentUser, bioInstance: bioInstance])
    return
    }
```

GSP:

```
<g:hasErrors beans="[bioInstance:Bio,user:User]">
    <ul class="alert alert-danger">
       <g:renderErrors beans="[bioInstance:Bio,user:User]" as="list"/>
    </ul>
</g:hasErrors>
```

Comment: Do you have a `toString()` method on your enum?

Comment: No I don't. Do I need one ?

Comment: Yes, also you should probably post more of your code so that it's easier to diagnose.  The controller method and a portion of the gsp page.  Thanks

Comment: I will post more code in a few hours when I get access to my laptop :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because grails renders error messages via *message(error: someError)* method. *someError* is an instance of *org.springframework.validation.FieldError*, which was created during validation phase, and it has only one argument to its message - the name of domain class itself. So, it's a binding error, not a validation error, which by default has 3 arguments: property name, domain class name and rejected value.

If you're using grails 2.3 and above - you can write a custom binder as described at http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding. Or use an integer field inside the domain class, write some constraints for it, and expose it to the outside via getter as enum.

Comment: That sounds a bit complicated to do. I was wondering if Grails could support that out of the box.